# How to perform bitwise operations on hexadecimal numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In my `bash` script I have a string containing a hexadecimal number, e.g. `hex="0x12345678"`. Is it possible to treat it as a hex number and do bit shifting on it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can easily bitshift such numbers in an arithmetic context:

```
$ hex="0x12345678"
$ result=$((hex << 1))
$ printf "Result in hex notation: 0x%x\n" "$result"
0x2468acf0
```

Answer (score 32):

Of course you can do bitwise operations (inside an [arithmetic expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)):

```
$ echo "$((0x12345678 << 1))"
610839792
```

Or:

```
$ echo "$(( 16#12345678 << 1 ))"
610839792
```

The value could be set in a variable as well:

```
$ var=0x12345678         # or var=16#12345678
$ echo "$(( var << 1 ))"
610839792
```

And you can do OR, AND, XOR and/or NOT:

```
$ echo "$(( 0x123456 | 0x876543 ))"
9925975
```

And to get the result in hex as well:

```
$ printf '%X\n' "$(( 0x12345678 | 0xDEADBEEF ))"     # Bitwise OR
DEBDFEFF

$ printf '%X\n' "$(( 0x12345678 & 0xDEADBEEF ))"     # Bitwise AND
12241668

$ printf '%X\n' "$(( 0x12345678 ^ 0xDEADBEEF ))"     # Bitwise XOR
CC99E897

$ printf '%X\n' "$(( ~ 0x2C8B ))"                    # Bitwise NOT
FFFFFFFFFFFFD374
```

The only detail with a bitwise not (`~`) is that it flips all **available** bits. If the number representation use 64 bits, the result will have 64 bits. All leading zero bits will be flipped to ones.

To limit such conversion, just use an AND:

```
$ printf '%X\n' "$(( ( ~ 0x2C8B ) & 0xFFFF ))"
D374
```

Note that a bitwise NOT `~` is **not** a logical NOT `!`. A logical NOT turns input into 0 or 1 only, not any other number.

```
$ printf '%X\n' "$(( ! 0xdead ))" "$(( ! 0 ))"
0
1
```

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).

Arithmetic expressions support base 16 numbers and all the usual `C` operators.

Example:

```
$ hex="0xff"
$ echo $(( hex >> 1 ))
127
```