# Bash bitwise operator

Tags: bash, syntax, bitwise-operators

Any idea why the below code is not working?

```
hex_var='a'
processed=((3 & $hex_var) | 8)
```

Still didn't get much about 'Arithmetic Expansion'!

Comment: I believe your post don't have much information, please add more information in it so that we could try to help you on same.

Comment: my bad, updated the question with correct variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your arithmetic expression is wrong.  Here is what you could do:

```
hex_var=0xa
processed=$(( (3 & $hex_var) | 8 ))
echo $processed # yields 10
```

Alternately, as suggested by Gordon Davisson, you could use the `#` notation to explicitly specify the base:

```
hex_var=a
processed=$(( (3 & 16#$hex_var) | 8 ))
```

See:

- [How to perform bitwise operations on hexadecimal numbers in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667382/how-to-perform-bitwise-operations-on-hexadecimal-numbers-in-bash)
- [Arithmetic Expansion - GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html)

Comment: Unless he actually wants the ASCII value of `'a'`, then it would be `printf -v myval "%d" "'a"` (but I suspect you are 100% correct)

Comment: You can also specify an explicit base for numeric literals with e.g. `16#`: myvar2=a; processed=$((3 & 16#$myvar2) | 8)`